# Wrap into Combine (Promise-Future) code with 2 completions/branches?

Tags: swift, future, combine, branch-prediction

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // Use a boolean to initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK and load ads once.
  private var isMobileAdsStartCalled = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Request an update for the consent information.
    UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate(with: nil) {
      [weak self] requestConsentError in
      guard let self else { return }

      if let consentError = requestConsentError {
        // Consent gathering failed.
        return print("Error: \(consentError.localizedDescription)")
      }

      UMPConsentForm.loadAndPresentIfRequired(from: self) {
        [weak self] loadAndPresentError in
        guard let self else { return }

        if let consentError = loadAndPresentError {
          // Consent gathering failed.
          return print("Error: \(consentError.localizedDescription)")
        }

        // Consent has been gathered.
        if UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.canRequestAds {
          self.startGoogleMobileAdsSDK()
        }
      }
    }
    
    // Check if you can initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK in parallel
    // while checking for new consent information. Consent obtained in
    // the previous session can be used to request ads.
    if UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.canRequestAds {
      startGoogleMobileAdsSDK()
    }
  }
  
  private func startGoogleMobileAdsSDK() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      guard !self.isMobileAdsStartCalled else { return }

      self.isMobileAdsStartCalled = true

      // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
      GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start()

      // TODO: Request an ad.
      // GADInterstitialAd.load(...)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to move viewDidLoad inner code and `startGoogleMobileAdsSDK()` as `Combine` methods which return `Future<Error, Never>` and/or `Future<(), Never>`. The problem is `UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate...` may call `GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start()` (google ads initialisation) or `viewDidLoad` may call the same method and I don't know how to handle such branches properly.

In the same time I can't write `promise(.success(()))` because it may be executed multiple times. How to resolve this issue correctly?

Comment: I have read through your code and read your explanation several times.  I do not understand the problem that you are running into.  `Future<Error, Never>` does not make much sense.  `Future<Void, Error>` seems like something you may be aiming for.  But I don't understand the issue with `GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.start()`.  Perhaps a Minimal Reproducible Example without all your domain specific code would help.

Comment: @ScottThompson the problem is when you usually create `Future` it has one completion or at least multiple completion calls in one chunk of code/task. In the example above I need somehow handle 2 completions which may or may not be called from 2 completely different task

Comment: A `Future` is a publisher that is expected to publish a single value and then finish.  It doesn't have a completion handler per se. Can you add a code sample with your unsuccessful attempt to use `Futures` and add comments to show where you are running into a problem?  The gap between what have given, and what you are trying to do, is too large.

Comment: @ScottThompson the problem is this code example is provided by Google and I can't just throw it away and replace with my own one. I understand it how a task "get UMP consent" which should have a single completion but I don't know how to deal with this concrete example. Maybe `Future` is not suitable for this case and I need a `Combine's publisher` for example